# Setting up sub sections with their own editors

Tags: routes

I'm new to Drupal (v7.21) and hoping to use it for a site that contains several sections each run by a separate owner and their team of editors. Just wanted to ask if it would be possible and how I could go about it. The type of flow I'm looking for is:

```
Main Site
- Forum
- Store

  Section One
  - Blog
  - Book

  Section Two
  - Blog
  - Book
```

As normal the Admin would have overall control with each section having an 'owner' that can edit their sections Blog, Articles etc. The owners would also be able to give an 'editor' role to other users so they can edit content within the section.

It would be helpful if the urls for the site were:

```
domain.com/
domain.com/forum/
domain.com/store/

domain.com/sectionone/
domain.com/sectionone/blog/
domain.com/sectionone/book/

domain.com/sectiontwo/
domain.com/sectiontwo/blog/
domain.com/sectiontwo/book/
```

If I haven't included enough information please let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organic Groups is probably what you're looking for. Checkout the following help resources.

- the module's project page: http://drupal.org/project/og
- NodeOne's [Learn Organic groups](http://nodeone.se/sv/node/35)
- Modules Unraveled's [Organic Groups](http://modulesunraveled.com/organic-groups)

Comment: Thanks. I've been going through NodeOne's videos and this module seems perfect for my needs. But from that I can't see how I would give each group a clean url of 'domain.com/groupone/' and how I would get content types within that to have 'domain.com/groupone/blog/' instead of 'domain.com/node/1'. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: With the Pathauto module, you can set a pattern for all Group paths such as /groups/[node:title] by going to admin/config/search/path/patterns.